# stringstream question

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

Here is some code that used to work with my code, but is having a problem now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;    
int main()
{
 stringstream out;
 out << 100;
 cout << out.str();
}
```

I get just blank output.  I just changed to snow leopard with Xcode 3.2.

Comment: Do you mean `#include <string>` instead of `#include <cstring>`? The former declares `std::string` which is the return type of `stringstream::str()`; the latter declares only irrelevant (for our purposes) C functions like `strcmp()` etc.

Comment: Other than `<fstream>` and `<cstring>` being superfluous (and, theoretically, `<string>` being missing), I don't see any problems with your code. It should work as it is. Have you run it from a shell or from within an IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get this exact same issue under the same conditions Snow Leopard 64-Bit XCode 3.2 Base SDK 10.6 and the switch to Base SDK 10.5 resolves it.

Apparently it's a SDK 10.6 issue.

and the correct workaround is to remove the preprocessor macros:

- _GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1
- _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC=1

From the preprocessor settings (or else fall back to SDK 10.5 as above).

[Apple Discussion Link](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2166586&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

it works for me. if there's a problem, it should be your gcc's.

btw, maybe you have to add fflush(stdout); after the cout <<  sometime the problem is stdout buffer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
 stringstream out;
 out << 100;
 cout << out.str();
 fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: This did not fix the problem, either.   I went to Project Settings in Xcode and changed the base SDK for all configurations from OS X 10.6 -> 10.5 and this fixed the problem.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @Fu4ny: The `std::flush` isn't really necessary in this case because the stream is flushed anyway when the program exits. (The only problem might be that Patrick has a breakpoint on the closing `}` and wonders why his output doesn't appear. But that's very unlikely.)

Comment: I don't really know why, but I just add flush to make sure that the stream is flushed.
Should be some problem with gcc or stdout

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is that you have a .o file left over from before you upgraded that's somehow messing things up.  Mixing .o files from two different versions of the C++ compiler can cause all kinds of strange problems.  I also do not discount the header file issue as well, though sstream should be including string.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you add the end of string before converting to string?

```
cout << out.str() << sdt::ends;
```