# string parsing to double fails in C++

Tags: c++, string, xcode, parsing, double

Here's a fun one I've been trying to figure out.  I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string s("5");
    istringstream stream(s);

    double theValue;
    stream >> theValue;

    cout << theValue << endl;
    cout << stream.fail();
}
```

The output is:

```
0
1
```

I don't understand why this is failing. Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

helixed

EDIT:

Okay, sorry to turn this into a [double post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633092/problem-with-istringstream-in-c), but this looks like a problem specific to Xcode.  If I compile this in g++, the code works without a problem.  Does anybody have an idea why this is happening in Xcode, and how I could possibly fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is the problem you're having: [stringstream question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377038/stringstream-question)

See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377038/stringstream-question/1756146#1756146) and the [link therein](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2166586&tstart=0).  An example in the Apple discussion link sounds very much like what you're experiencing.

Comment: So that was the problem. It fixed the output for both of my posts. It's amazing Apple would let a bug like this slip through. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that's exactly what you're building? I get `5` and `0` as expected

Comment: Okay, so this works fine in g++. I edited my post above. Thanks for the quick reply.